# append two decimal places at the end of a model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model that holds digits in this format

```
10000000
200000000
3000000000
70000000
```

and here is the model

```
{{myData}}
```

I am able to format the data but that appends two decimal places at the front of the variable using this

```
{{myData | number : 2}} which prints 100.00000
```

how to achieve this on the variables is my challenge

```
100000.00
```

Comment: That filter does not produce what you are saying it does

Comment: yes it does not I was looking for a way to truncate two zeros from the last of a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 100 and use `toFixed()` on result

```
{{ (myData/100).toFixed(2) }}
```

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
   $scope.myData = 1000
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app"  ng-controller="Ctrl">
     {{(myData/100).toFixed(2)}}
   </div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: If you want thousands separators can use `number:2` filter instead after dividing

Comment: `{{ (myData/100) | number:2 }}`

Comment: the two produced same result

Answer (score -1):

You can use toFixed() to do that

view:

```
<div>
  {{parseFloat(myData).toFixed(2)}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.parseFloat = parseFloat;
$scope.myData = 1000
```

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/3ROw6aKdfCwwTdYp0rJi?p=preview

Comment: can I achieve this in the view and not in the javascript code

Comment: @user10445503 you have to add the parseFloat method in $scope. Here is example http://plnkr.co/edit/3ROw6aKdfCwwTdYp0rJi?p=preview

Comment: I think u do not get what I mean >>> if you parse 1000 it should be 10.00 as the outcome

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use in angular html view, where you dynamically render the value as:

```
{{ parseFloat(myData).toFixed(2) }}
```